# js2-mode: How to avoid automatically inserting space after a function call

Tags: js2-mode

For example, in js2-mode, when I type the following:

```
console.log(
```

the editor outputs this (assuming the `|` is my cursor):

```
console.log (|)
```

Why is there a space inserted between the function and the parenthesis? How can I disable this? I have explored the options under `M-x customize-group RET js2-mode`, but I have not found any setting to disable this feature.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think `js2-mode` has anything to do with this. Maybe you have another minor mode enabled that does this or some custom configuration.